# Plotting a Graph Live, Shifting Points Backwards as Time Progresses

Tags: java, processing

Processing is an environment that makes use of Java. I am trying to to use the Monte Carlo method to calculate the value of Pi.

Processing uses a coordinate system where the top left corner is the origin, rightwards is the positive x-axis, and downwards is the positive y-axis.

I made a graph that plots the calculated value of pi, using xCoordinate = xCoordinate + 1 as the number of random numbers used in the calculation (also known as darts in the darts analogy). However, using xCoordinate = xCoordinate + 1 as the number of random numbers increases to plot the graph has proven to be a very limited method due to the finite horizontal space, as the points wander off to points off of the screen. How can I make the graph such that the newest value is always added to a constant xCoordinate, with the previous values shifting backwards as the number of random points increases?

My code currently is:

```
float inCircle = 0;
float inSquare = 0;
float xCoordinate = 600;

void setup() {
  size(1200, 600);
  background(50);
  frameRate(50);
  line(0, 360, 360, 360);
  line(360, 0, 360, 360);
}

void draw() {  
  // inCircle and inSquare are updated
  // ...

  if (inSquare == 0.0) {    
    print("Calculating...");  
  } else {  
    println(inCircle / inSquare);
    line(600, 300, 1200, 300); // x = 3.14
    line(600, 345, 1200, 345); // x = 3
    line(600, 25, 1200, 25); // x = 4

    // Draw Pi estimate (y-axis) at xCoordinate
    ellipse(xCoordinate, 300-(320*((inCircle / inSquare)-3.14159265)), 1, 1);

    xCoordinate = xCoordinate + 1;        
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to plot your estimate of Pi as a time series, where on the y-axis you plot the estimate of Pi and on the x-axis you have the number of data points used for your estimate, right? And when the number of data points gets larger than the drawing area width, you want to only draw the newest k points that fit into the drawing area, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the code that is not relevant for this question. But I recommend you show what you've already tried, otherwise this question might get flagged as "too broad"

Comment: As for the actual solution to your problem, you add the each newly calculated estimate to a list and then only draw the newest _k_ points. You'd have to redraw all those _k_ points after each update, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only drawing one point every frame, store the points in a data structure (like an `ArrayList`) and redraw the whole graph each frame. As points "fall off" the left of the window, simply remove them from the data structure.

You could also try to drawing to a `PGraphics` buffer instead of directly to the screen and then offsetting the buffer, but you'd eventually reach the same problem. So just store your points in an `ArrayList` and only draw the ones you want.